# How do I fix duplicate entries in sources.list?

Tags: apt, software-sources

Ok so I have tried everything under the sun but can't get into my `sources.list` to fix the duplicate and I think that's why my Software Center isn't working as well.

This is what I get when I do `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
christina@owner-laptop:~$ /etc/apt/sources.list
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied
christina@owner-laptop:~$
```

Then, when I do `sudo apt-get update`, this is what I get:

```
christina@owner-laptop:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
Ign http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease                
Ign http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com karmic-backports InRelease               
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                      
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg              
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com karmic-backports Release.gpg             
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Ign http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise Release                          
Ign http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release                  
Ign http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com karmic-backports Release                 
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease                      
Ign http://archive.canonical.com karmic InRelease                              
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise InRelease                             
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                     
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources     
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources       
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources     
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages     
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release              
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages         
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages           
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US  
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en              
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en_US     
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en        
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en_US
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en_US       
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en          
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources   
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en_US
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com karmic-backports/main Sources  
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com karmic-backports/restricted Sources
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com karmic-backports/universe Sources
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Ign http://archive.canonical.com quantal InRelease                             
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com karmic-backports/multiverse Sources      
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com karmic-backports/main i386 Packages      
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com karmic-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com karmic-backports/universe i386 Packages
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com karmic-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com karmic-backports/main Translation-en_US
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com karmic-backports/main Translation-en
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com karmic-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com karmic-backports/multiverse Translation-en
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com karmic-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com karmic-backports/restricted Translation-en
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com karmic-backports/universe Translation-en_US
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com karmic-backports/universe Translation-en
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources         
Hit http://archive.canonical.com karmic Release.gpg                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal Release.gpg
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.canonical.com karmic Release
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages   
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.canonical.com karmic/partner i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Sources
Hit http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.canonical.com karmic/partner Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.canonical.com karmic/partner Translation-en
Ign http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.canonical.com quantal/partner Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en_US
W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-backports/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-backports/main/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-backports/restricted/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-backports/universe/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-backports/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-backports/main/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-backports/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-backports/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-backports/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-backports/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic-backports/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

any suggestions

Comment: Apart of duplicated entries, you are mixing releases and have a weird hostname there. Delete all lines with `us.old-releases.ubuntu.com`.